# Couldnot load file or assembly for Coded UI

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, coded-ui-tests

I'm getting an exception while debugging my code in VS2010 premium. Its about version of the  dll that I'm using

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.Communication.Interop
```

> Couldnot load file or assembly
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.IE.Communication.Interop
>   version=9.0.0.0

Which version of the dll is to be used and where it is available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> We are getting this exception because the dll is missing in the
>   solution bin folder. If you are debugging the solution keep the dll
>   under the folder Debug, or else release then keep it under the folder
>   Release. If you are adding reference by using the option 'add
>   reference', may be it won't be in these folders, so it happens to get
>   this exception. So if you are getting this exception make sure that
>   dll is added properly.